# Event is not fired after clicking Facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events

I am trying to get this event FB Subscribe event fired `(alert('hi'))` but it does not seem to work though:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Facebook Like Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'myappid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        targetUrl="http://www.goal.com";
        FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function () {
            console.log('xfbml.render');
            FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function (targetUrl) {
                console.log('edge.create');
                alert('hi');    
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove", function (targetUrl) {
                console.log('edge.remove');
            });
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
<fb:like></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would try to use the edge.create event OUTSIDE the xfbml.render event callback function :_)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that edge.create event isn't fired on localhost. After uploading to test server which is visible by Facebook, it worked.

Also, As Rufinus suggested, subscribe to those events outside of xfbml.render callback function.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: 'myappid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    targetUrl="http://www.goal.com";
    FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function () {
        console.log('xfbml.render');
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function (targetUrl) {
        console.log('edge.create');
        alert('hi');    
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove", function (targetUrl) {
        console.log('edge.remove');
    });
};
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
</script>
```