# Facebook LIKE-button using jquery

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this simple Facebook-app. It uses jQuery and has been made according to Facebook's own specifications and sample code. The app is only available for visitors, who have liked the page.

I've succeded in building it in PHP, but for other reasons, I need it made in Javascript instead. However, the "has-user-liked-page" function doesn't fire and I've tried a dozen solutions like this: [event is not fired after clicking facebook like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018285/event-is-not-fired-after-clicking-facebook-like-button)

Now, the Facebook documentation recommends this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe

The perhaps most relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
....
<body>
<div id="fb-root"><iframe id="contentIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
                $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
                    FB.init({
                        appId: '247171102105...',
                        channelUrl: 'https://facebook.****.com/customer1/test/channel.html',
                    }); 

                    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
                        alert('You liked the URL: ' + href);
                    });

                    FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
                });
            });

            function updateStatusCallback() {           
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                            document.getElementById("contentIframe").src = "kalender.php?userID="+response.id+"&userName="+response.name+"&email="+response.email;
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
                        });
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("contentIframe").src = "fallback.php";
                    }
                }, {scope:'email,publish_stream,user_photos'});
                FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
            }
    </script>
    ....
```

Do you have a clue, why the alert-command is never fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long night, I found a solution. I combined PHP and jQuery API, so that the PHP-part checks for like. jQuery handles everything else - permissions, forwarding etc. It's not very elegant, but I found no other way.

This in the top of the file:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '247171102105***',
        'secret' => '************************',
    ));
    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
    if ($like_status == 1) {
        $url = "kalender";
    } else {
        $url = "userDoesntLike";
    }
```

And in the Javascript-part:

```
function updateStatusCallback() {           
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                document.getElementById("contentIframe").src = "<?=$url;?>.php?userID="+response.id+"&userName="+response.name+"&email="+response.email;
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
});
            } else {
                document.getElementById("contentIframe").src = "fallback.php";
            }
        }, {scope:'email,publish_stream,user_photos'});
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```